# Proteger links a través de Verificación de Google

Tags: javascript, html

Soy muy novato en cuanto a programar y quería hacer lo siguiente:

Tener una página web en el cual uno inicie sesión con Google y si uno inicia sesión con ciertos correos te redirige a otra página.

Soy parte de una organización de la cual tengo la dirección de correo electrónico de todos (las cuales quiero mantener en privado) y la idea idea es que ellos pueden acceder a la página web, inicien sesión con Google y la página los redirija si iniciaron sesión con las cuentas autorizadas

Pude implementar bien el inicio de sesión con Google pero no logro hacer el resto.

Estaría muy agradecido si me pueden ayudar en mi primer proyecto :)

Comment: Para ayudar de mejor manera nos puede dar información de las tecnoligías que está usando (backend y frontend), gracias.

Comment: Si lograste ya que pudieran acceder a sus cuentas de google no creo que sea tan dificil redirigir al usuario...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

bueno leí tu publicación y depende si estás con php puedes hacer de que cuando hagas el correcto inicio de sesión seguido valide el correo y se envié a un login o sitio donde quieres que sea enviado, ya sea cargando una cookie con el correo encriptado o simplemente un clásico (if) como:

```
<?php
// todo tu código de validación Google
// verificar que tu correo tenga un gmail.
$email='juanito@gmail.com';
if(!empty(strpos('gmail',$email)))
{
header('Location: /admin-gmail.php'):
}
?>
```

a claro que esto es a **modo muy básico**, ya que que se puede modificar para ser más seguro o **validar muchos correos** etc.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero considera revisar [answer], Saludos.